# Is DCFL closed under union with RL?

Tags: regular-languages, context-free, pushdown-automata

So i know that DCFL is not closed under union, but what about union with RL?

Because what if both of the languages can start with the same string?then when we are building the DPDA for the union and for example both of them can start with $a$ then how can we determine whether its for the RL or for the DCFL?